# Hadoop hive serde - Input format must implement InputFormat

Tags: hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

I have worked upon a SerDe to process my XML data and in that create the custom InputFormat and RecordRedaer for XML data.

Below is the signature for the classes -

SerDe class -

```
public class XMLSerde extends AbstractSerDe {
```

InputFormat -

```
public class XMLInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, BookWritable> {

    @Override
    public RecordReader<LongWritable, BookWritable> createRecordReader(InputSplit arg0,
            TaskAttemptContext arg1) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new XMLRecordReader();
    }
```

RecordReader -

```
public class XMLRecordReader extends RecordReader<LongWritable, BookWritable> {
```

BookWritable is the custom Writable class which i have created.

Now when i am using this serde as below -

```
CREATE TABLE xml_items(Author STRING, Title STRING, ISBN STRING) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.xml.serde.XMLSerde' STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.xml.serde.XMLInputFormat';
```

I am getting below error while running a select query on this table.

```
FAILED: SemanticException 1:14 Input format must implement InputFormat. Error encountered near token 'books'
```

Please suggest.
AJ

Comment: Any help on this please...

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports only the old mareduce API. 
You should inherit XMLInputFormat from the org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat class.

Comment: Dont know how readable it is -

`package com.xml.serde;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.*;

public class XMLInputFormat extends FileInputFormat<LongWritable, BookWritable> {

 @Override
 public RecordReader<LongWritable, BookWritable> getRecordReader(
   InputSplit arg0, JobConf arg1, Reporter arg2) throws IOException {
  return new XMLRecordReader(arg1, (FileSplit)arg0);
 }
}`

Comment: XMLRecordReader also must implements interface from old MapRecuce API - org.apache.hadoop.mapred.RecordReader.

Comment: Ya i did that, it was like sort of mandatory while extending the mapred fileinputformat...

Comment: Could you show table creation script? Also may be you use jar with your old class.

Comment: table creation script -

`CREATE TABLE books(author STRING, title STRING, isbn STRING)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.xml.serde.XMLSerde'
    STORED AS
    INPUTFORMAT 'com.xml.serde.XMLInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';`

Comment: and which jars? serde one or the mapred/hdfs ones?

Comment: Jar with your serde and input format. You should rebuild this jar and re add it to hive:
delete jar 'path/to/old/jar';
add jar 'path/to/new/jar';

Comment: Hi @AJ84, Did this approach worked, as I am also hitting on the same issue. I have to use a customised FixedLengthInputFormat and FixedLengthRecordReader. Should it be in old mapred api and did this worked? Kindly share your experience. Thanks.